# Powering a device from an unknown circuit - voltage drops from 3.3 to 3.2. Is it overloaded?

Tags: voltage-regulator

I want to power an ESP8266 (wemos D1 Mini) directly off of a 3.3v power source provided by my garage door opener. This was never intended by the manufacturer, but it would be very convenient.

I observe that when I connect the ESP to the door opener, the voltage drops from 3.28v to 3.20v.

Is this voltage drop an indication that the ESP8266 is overloading the voltage regulator?

Comment: no, but it proves there is resistance x current = 2% drop within a normal range, but that will increase the regulator temperature

Comment: Doubtful. That's a fairly small drop and stuff designed for 3.3V should work on 3.2V. If in doubt though, draw up a schematic of the garage door opener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not necessarily an indication of overloading, but it most certainly should not be taken as a sign that it is "okay".

The ESP draws current in relatively large spikes so measurement with a multimeter may not give a true indication of what is happening (you'd need an oscilloscope) and there may also be thermal factors (there could be a regulator overheated and close to failure or thermal limiting when the air temperature rises in summer, for example).

Comment: I do have a scope. I can see a pretty consistent mean voltage of 3.20v when the ESP is idle. I read that the ESP's power consumption will rise when transmitting data, so I plan to test that and see if the voltage drops at all. Is there any other sort of test you would recommend?

Comment: Trace out the circuit and see exactly what you are loading. It would be unusual for a designer of a cost-constrained device like a garage door opener to put a lot of unused capacity in a power supply. That kind of thing tends to lead to unemployment, since even a few pennies per unit adds up. It may, in fact, be perfectly fine, but there is no way to know that without knowing almost as much as the original designer knew, plus the requirements of the ESP.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better measurement of power quality looking at the noise on the supply when it transmits RF with a large current dynamic range.    Be sure to filter the supply near the load to reduce the change of interference.

Drawing more current for brief durations is not a major concern to the source regulator, but long durations with a unknown % inefficiency loss at source, may contribute to regulator temperature rise on the garage card.

But likely the convenience outweighs the risk.

Current consumption 15 µA – 400 mA  [ESP 8266 shield](https://diyi0t.com/technical-datasheet-microcontroller-comparison/)

[Microcontroller    ESP8266](https://diyi0t.com/esp8266-wemos-d1-mini-tutorial/)

Processor   Tensilica Xtensa Diamond 32-bit
Operating Voltage   3.3V
Minimum Operating Voltage   2.58V
Maximum Operating Voltage   3.6V